# how to make awk print 3 items on the same line then switch to a new line

Tags: awk

I am trying to parse the output of my top results to pickout the timestamp, used Mem and used Swap:

```
top - 12:06:52 up  3:36, 37 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.02, 0.00
Tasks: 563 total,   1 running, 562 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65968400k total,  9594508k used, 56373892k free,   199136k buffers
Swap: 68026360k total,        0k used, 68026360k free,  5864056k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                    
11527 root      15   0 26464 1728 1056 R  1.9  0.0   0:00.01 top
```

So that's a sample of it. Now I got the awk cmd below:

```
awk '$1 ~/top/ {print $5;} $1 ~/Mem/ {print $4;} $1 ~/Swap/  {print $4;}' top-output
```

But it is not perfect because it outputs everything in a new line. Like this:

```
7:40,
12644016k
0k
7:50,
12411248k
0k 
8:04,
12795392k
0k
```

I want it to output like this instead:

```
7:40, 12644016k, 0k
7:50, 12411248k, 0k
```

How do I do that?
Thanks

Comment: This has been asked on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021982/awk-without-printing-newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `printf`:

```
$ awk '$1 ~/top/ {printf "%s ",$5;} $1 ~/Mem/ {printf "%s ",$4;} $1 ~/Swap/  {print $4;}' top-output
3:36, 9594508k 0k
```

`printf` offers flexible formatting and it does not, unless you explicitly tell it to, print a newline character.  The first argument to `printf` is the format string for `printf`.  The format string is documented in `man awk`.

Another method to save the values and use `print` just once:

```
$ awk '$1 ~/top/ {up=$5;} $1 ~/Mem/ {used=$4;} $1 ~/Swap/  {print up,used,$4;}' top-output
3:36, 9594508k 0k
```

#### Adding the extra comma

```
$ awk '$1 ~/top/ {printf "%s ",$5;} $1 ~/Mem/ {printf "%s, ",$4;} $1 ~/Swap/  {print $4;}' top-output
3:36, 9594508k, 0k

$ awk '$1 ~/top/ {up=$5;} $1 ~/Mem/ {used=$4;} $1 ~/Swap/  {print up,used",",$4;}' top-output
3:36, 9594508k, 0k
```

#### Stripping out the `k`

With printf, we can specify an integer format and that forces conversion to a number which removes the `k`:

```
$ awk '$1 ~/top/ {printf "%s ",$5;} $1 ~/Mem/ {printf "%i, ",$4;} $1 ~/Swap/  {print $4;}' top-output
3:36, 9594508, 0k
```

Another way to force a conversion to a number is to add zero to it.  Thus, the following uses `used=$4+0` in place of `used=$4`:

```
$ awk '$1 ~/top/ {up=$5;} $1 ~/Mem/ {used=$4+0;} $1 ~/Swap/  {print up,used",",$4;}' top-output
3:36, 9594508, 0k
```

#### Removing the comma from the uptime

The uptime has a colon between two numbers and awk cannot convert it to a number.  That means that other approaches are needed.  One way to make the comma disappear from the output is adding a comma to the field separator:

```
$ awk -F'[,[:space:]]+' '$1 ~/top/ {printf "%s ",$5;} $1 ~/Mem/ {printf "%s ",$4;} $1 ~/Swap/  {print $4;}' top-output
3:36 9594508k 0k

$ awk -F'[,[:space:]]+' '$1 ~/top/ {up=$5;} $1 ~/Mem/ {used=$4+0;} $1 ~/Swap/  {print up,used,$4;}' top-output
3:36 9594508 0k
```

Comment: sweet thanks! Just a quick followup how do I strip out the k?

Comment: @D.Zou Your welcome.  The answer is updated with versions that remove the `k`.

Comment: why does adding a zero force it to drop the k?

Comment: In awk, variables can be treated as either string or number, depending on context.  Addition forces a numeric context.  This is true even for simple operations like adding zero.  The numeric context means that awk has to convert the string `9594508k`  to a number which, in this case, is `9594508`.

Comment: sorry for another question, what if I want to strip out the comma after the timestamp? I tried it to add the zero and %i but neither results were correct.

Comment: @D.Zou Yes, awk does not know how to convert hour:minute to a number and, even if it did, you probably wouldn't like the result.  I updated the answer with a simple method to remove the comma from uptime.